# Matrix multiplication in C#

Tags: c#, matrix

I'm having problems multiplying two matrices of dimensions 5000x1024.
I tried to do it through loops in a conventional manner, but it takes forever.
Is there any good library with implemented and optimized matrix operations, or any algorithm that does it without 3 loops?

Comment: it is not C#, but algorithmic problem. and yes, the multiplication of matrices of such size will take some time even if you use Strassen's algorithm.

Comment: i know it's not C# problem i just referenced it so that people would know in which language i'm working

Comment: btw ... i want to multiply Atranspose*A and then divide all elements with number of columns

Comment: Is this an arbitrary matrix, or is there some structure? Is it sparse for example? If there is no structure very little that can be done.

Comment: it contains byte data for pixels in pictures , so there is no regularity as it depends form case to case

Comment: Are you trying to perform some sort of image manipulation? A matrix multiplication might not be the most efficient method. 2D Fourier, etc. can be really useful in some circumstances.

Comment: @МилошЧолић `A-transpose * A` will give you a square matrix with [linear independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) columns, therefore, the resulting matrix will be an [invertible matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix). I'm not sure how could it help you, as I can not see the problem you are trying to solve, but I'll be happy to know that it helps somehow :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked into using OpenCL? One of the examples in the Cloo (C# OpenCL library) distribution is a large 2D matrix multiplication.

Unlike CUDA, OpenCL kernels will run on your GPU (if available and supported) or the CPU. On the GPU you'll see really, really, really dramatic speed increases. I mean, *really* dramatic, on the order of 10x-100x depending on how efficient your kernel is and how many cores your GPU has. (A Fermi-based NVidia card will have between 384-512, and the new 600's have something like 1500.)

If you're not interested in going that route - though anyone that's doing numerically-intensive, easily parallelizable operations like this should be using the GPU - make sure you're at least using C#'s built-in parallelization:

```
Parallel.For(
  0
  ,5000
  , (i) => { 
    for(var j=0;j<1024;j++)
    {
      result[i,j] = .....
    }
);
```

also, check out GPU.NET and Brahma. Brahma lets you build OpenCL kernels in C# with LINQ. Definitely lowers the learning curve.

Comment: I found [Brahma on codeplex](http://brahma.codeplex.com/) and [Brahma (alpha) on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/brahma-fx/) - both seem abandoned. The same goes for [Gpu.Net on Github](https://github.com/tidepowerd/GPU.NET-Example-Projects) the company website http://www.tidepowerd.com is no longer online.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) which has a runtime of approx. O(n<sup>2.8</sup>) instead of O(n<sup>3</sup>) with a naive method of multiplying matrices. One problem is that is not always stable but works fine for really high dimensions. Furthermore it is really complex so I would suggest you to rethink your design and maybe decrease the size of the matrix or split your problem into smaller pieces.

But keep in mind that a matrix multiplication with no special properties (like [Aidan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257338/aidan) mentioned) is nearly impossible to optimize. Here an example: the [Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) takes O(n<sup>2.3737</sup>) and it is by far one of the best algorithms for matrix multiplication! The best option here would be to either use OpenCL and the GPU (mentioned by [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135769/david-lively)) or to look at other optimized programming languages like Python with the package `numpy`.

Good luck either way!

Comment: i'm using it for PCA reduction for Neural Networks so i must put all knowledge in one matrix and compute with it